# Insert a node in between existing nodes

Tags: java, insert, nodes

I have an insert method and I need help with inserting a new node between two nodes

Here's the code:

```
@Override
public void insert(int index, E data) throws ListOverflowException {
    Node<E> curr = startOfNode;
    int ctr = 0;

    // adds the data in the specified index in the linked list
    for (curr = startOfNode; curr !=null; curr = curr.getNext()) {
        if (ctr == index) {
            Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(data);
            curr.setNext(newNode);
            newNode.setNext(curr.getNext());
            break;
        }
        ctr++;
    }

    if (size == maxSize) {
        throw new ListOverflowException("Error! Can't add any more nodes");
    }
}
```

This is the initial list:

```
Item 1 :4
Item 2 :5
Item 3 :6
Item 4 :8
Item 5 :9
Item 6 :null
```

and here's the result that I get. As you can see the nodes that holds number 8 and 9 gets lost. How do I modify the loop to get the desired result:

```
Item 1 :4
Item 2 :5
Item 3 :6
Item 4 :7
Item 5 :null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first approach is flawed, because you omit all nodes from the index you are inserting at, therefore losing all links.

In your second approach you have the right idea, but you get an infinite loop, because you do `curr.getNext()` **after** inserting the new node. The solution is to get the node **before** inserting the new node, saving it temporarily, adding the new node and setting the temporarily saved node as the next to the inserted node.

It should look something like this:

```java
Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(data);
Node<E> tempNode = curr.getNext(); // retrieve the initially following node
curr.setNext(newNode);             // insert the new node
newNode.setNext(tempNode);         // reconstruct the link
```

Comment: I see. Now I get why it loses the nodes after the current node. Thank you!